# Can I force Jena (ARQ) to execute my query plan?

Tags: optimization, sparql, jena, arq

I am working with Jena (ARQ) and I have generated a new query plan. I am not sure how exactly can I ask Jena to execute my query plan instead of generating its own optimized/reordered query plan.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you have to extend the query execution: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/arq-query-eval.html

Comment: As others have answered yes, whether it is advisable is another matter entirely. Years of work have gone into Jena's optimiser to ensure that it preserves the semantics of the queries it is given.  Yes a general purpose optimiser will not work for all possible queries and some queries may be made worse by the optimiser.  By generating your own plan you may be subtly changing the semantics of the query in ways that aren't even obvious to you i.e. are you unintentionally sacrificing correctness for performance?

Answer (score 2):

[Answered on dev@jena](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r2e2baecc3972e993c80573d740fd77fc143d5c8065bfc4fe99d93116%40%3Cdev.jena.apache.org%3E) where it was asked the day before.

Answers can't always be provided the same day.
Please don't ask in multiple places unless you yourself are going to copy answers/links to all the places.